# Understanding Chrome's basic call stack structure

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

The following code reveals some of Chrome's internal call stack workings:

```
(function revealCallStack() {
    var fn = arguments.callee;
    console.log('**Bottom of stack**:\n\n', fn);
    while (fn = fn.caller) console.log('**Next on stack**:\n\n', fn);
})();
```

Please see http://jsfiddle.net/fW5Ag/. The piece of code reveals four functions on the stack. The first two are somewhat predictable. What about the last two (pasted below)?

```
function (event){
    if (custom.condition.call(this, event, type)) return fn.call(this, event);
    return true;
}
```

and

```
function (event){
    event = new DOMEvent(event, self.getWindow());
    if (condition.call(self, event) === false) event.stop();
}
```

What exactly is happening here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are the Mootools and jsFiddle functions for onload execution of Javascript, not browser functions.

Try noWrap and no library: http://jsfiddle.net/fW5Ag/1/